# Update Postgresql from MSSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, odoo

I have a Python script that creates records from MSSQL to Postgresql (Odoo). What I would like to try and do now is to update existing fields and create if they do not already exist. My script is

```
#Retrieve data through recordset
RecCount =rs.RecordCount

print RecCount

while not rs.EOF:
    #  print rs.Fields.item('Description').value
    #  print rs.Fields.item('Price').value
    name = rs.Fields.item('Description').value
    barcode = rs.Fields.item('ItemLookupCode').value
    categ_id = rs.Fields.item('ItemLookupCode').value
    record = {'name' : name, 'barcode' : barcode}
    #recordbarcode = {'barcode' : barcode}

    filter = [[['barcode' ,'=', barcode]]]
    product_id = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'search', filter)

    if not product_id:
        print " Create - " + barcode
        resultset = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'create', [record] )
        #product_id = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'create', product_id)

    else:
        print "Product Barcode is already in the table - " + barcode


        #resultset = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd,
        #   'product.template', 'search', [record]
        #resultset = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd,
        #'product.template', 'create', [record])
        # filter, {'fields': ['name','list_price'], 'limit': 50})
    rs.Move(1)
```

I tried the below but I get  `result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)\nTypeError: write() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)\n'>`

**Code that does not Update**

```
print RecCount

while not rs.EOF:
    #  print rs.Fields.item('Description').value
    #  print rs.Fields.item('Price').value
    name = rs.Fields.item('Description').value
    barcode = rs.Fields.item('ItemLookupCode').value
    categ_id = rs.Fields.item('ItemLookupCode').value
    record = {'name' : name, 'barcode' : barcode}
    #recordbarcode = {'barcode' : barcode}

    #filter = [[['barcode' ,'=', barcode]]]
    #product_id = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'search', filter)


    #if not product_id:
    #   print " Create - " + barcode
    #   resultset = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'write', [record] )
        #product_id = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'create', product_id)
    result = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd, 'product.template', 'write', [record] )

    #else:
        #print "Product Barcode is already in the table - " + barcode


        #resultset = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd,
        #   'product.template', 'search', [record]
        #resultset = OdooApi.execute_kw(database, uid, pwd,
        #'product.template', 'create', [record])
        # filter, {'fields': ['name','list_price'], 'limit': 50})
    rs.Move(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the `write` method, but on which record do you want to write to?

When you use xmlrpc to invoke the write method on the Odoo server you need to pass two parameters:

1) The id of the record on the `product.template` module that you want to write these `record` values to.

2) The actual dictionary that contains the `{field:value_of_field}` values.

When you use the `create` method you get back an id, pass that id on your `write` method along with the values that you want to write to it.